# Is there really no way to expose the prototype of a html element in IE (<8)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, prototype-programming

I cooked up a pattern to create and extend html elements using their prototype. This works like a charm in non-ie browsers. <strike>Example code can be found @jsbin</strike><sup>**1**</sup>

The advantage of this pattern should be speed (the methods are in the elements prototype chain, so they are referenced once). You guessed right: IE no go. In IE < 8 the prototype of html elements is hidden/not accessible, so for every element you create, you have to reference the non standard methods again (leaving you with a lot of pointers if you use the pattern intensively). I have searched the web for solutions, but only found complex workarounds. Is there *really* no way to access a HTML elements prototype in IE?

<sup>**1**</sup> Alas: the jsbin code is lost in clouds.

Comment: Is the prototype of html elements available in IE8? If so, how is it accessed?

Comment: It is, as far as I understood. And it is accessed via the prototype (like document.getElementById('someelement').prototype). In the mean time I wrote a DOM-wrapper to be able to use leak free javascript.

Comment: @Helephant Yes, it's accessible. You can access, for example, `Element.prototype` and add methods to it. This is guaranteed by the latest version of the [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/), which defines things like `Element` as [WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL) interfaces, which carries with it the explicit implication that they should be accessible in the global scope and their prototypes should be modifiable.

Comment: Hey @KoolInc, your comment above from 2009 is erroneous (`document.getElementById('someelement').prototype` will throw a `TypeError`; perhaps you could just delete it and then flag this comment of mine as obsolete for a mod to mop up?

Comment: @MarkAmery: are you sure? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900(VS.85).aspx#domproto. `document.getElementById('some').prototype` returns `undefined` in IE8 (so, not a `TypeError`), `document.getElementById('some').constructor.prototype` returns the prototype.

Comment: @KoolInc whoops, sorry, you're quite right that what you wrote will return undefined if the element exists (I was clearly testing on an element that wasn't actually present.) In any case it's still wrong since you haven't got the `.constructor` in what you originally wrote; constructors have the `prototype` property, but instances do not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, nor is it guaranteed you can fiddle with DOM objects' prototypes in JavaScript in general. The DOM objects are not part of the ECMAScript spec; they may not be (and traditionally speaking aren't) native JavaScript Objects at all, in any browser.

This is why frameworks tend to have their own ‘container’ wrapper classes.

Also you cannot rely on ‘t.el.constructor’ even if they were native JS Objects. ‘constructor’ is not a standard property, isn't available in IE, and even in Mozilla doesn't do what you might think it does. Avoid.

Comment: Much of this is obsolete, and I'm not sure it was all true even when posted. Both the old [DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/ecma-script-binding.html) and current [DOM Living Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/) make explicit reference to *constructors* when specifying interfaces, and the [ECMAScript 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (see section 4.2.1) and [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.4) specs dictate that a constructor has a `prototype` property.

Comment: Additionally, the constructor property *was* specced for native objects in ECMAScript 3; just CTRL-F for `.constructor` or `constructor property` in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf. They remain specced in ECMAScript 5. It *does* seem true, though, that there's no general rule that a constructor's `prototype` property must have a `constructor` property pointing back to the constructor, so I think host objects could have a silly `constructor` property without technically violating spec, but in practice they don't.

Comment: Additionally, in the latest version of the [DOM Living Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/), all the DOM objects are guaranteed to behave sensibly, since they are declared using [WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL), which dictates, among other things, that an interface object must exist as a property of the global object unless `NoInterfaceObject` is specified, and that prototype objects must have `constructor` properties pointing to the interface object. So what little spec ambiguity remained back in 2009 and now tidied up.

Comment: Of course, IE 7 wasn't spec-compliant, so this answer was *practically* correct in 2009. I'm just not sure it was *strictly* correct, assuming that we're meant to interpret 'guaranteed' and 'standard' as 'guaranteed by spec'. All that said, thank you for making remarks (six years ago) that prompted me (today) to dive into where and how all these things were specced. I have spent an enjoyable few hours getting to grips with all this stuff, and feel lawyerly and empowered with all my new spec knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there really is no way to do this.

IE elements are based COM objects which actually don't allow arbitary members to be added to their interfaces (in COM, interfaces are a contract and should never change).  Implementation of these interfaces cannot be extended by Javascript, the elements simply are not prototypal.

IE adds a special interface designed to work with Javascript to allow the addition of new members to a specific instance but you cannot add a new member to 'class' since there is no prototype to fiddle with.

Answer (score 0):

The following, cut and pasted from the article [HTMLElement doesnt work in IE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/iewebdevelopment/thread/40d2534e-9054-4de0-bca8-b52c7bbc1eef).  Examples works perfectly in IE and Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DOMElement.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var DOMElement =
        {
            extend: function(name,fn)
            {
                if(!document.all)
                    eval("HTMLElement.prototype." + name + " = fn");
                else
                {
                    //
                    //  IE doesn't allow access to HTMLElement
                    //  so we need to override
                    //  *document.createElement
                    //  *document.getElementById
                    //  *document.getElementsByTagName
                    //

                    //take a copy of
                    //document.createElement
                    var _createElement = document.createElement;

                    //override document.createElement
                    document.createElement = function(tag)
                    {
                        var _elem = _createElement(tag);
                        eval("_elem." + name + " = fn");
                        return _elem;
                    }

                    //take copy of
                    //document.getElementById
                    var _getElementById = document.getElementById;

                    //override document.getElementById
                    document.getElementById = function(id)
                    {
                        var _elem = _getElementById(id);
                        eval("_elem." + name + " = fn");
                        return _elem;
                    }

                    //take copy of
                    //document.getElementsByTagName
                    var _getElementsByTagName = document.getElementsByTagName;

                    //override document.getElementsByTagName
                    document.getElementsByTagName = function(tag)
                    {
                        var _arr = _getElementsByTagName(tag);
                        for(var _elem=0;_elem<_arr.length;_elem++)
                            eval("_arr[_elem]." + name + " = fn");
                        return _arr;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        DOMElement.extend("foo",function(){alert('bar')});
        DOMElement.extend("about","DOMElement v0.1")
        DOMElement.extend("contents",function(){return this.innerHTML})
        var elem = document.createElement("div");
        elem.foo();

        onload = function()
        {
            var elem2 = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            alert(elem2.about);

            var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
                alert(divs[i].contents())
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="myDiv">hi</div>
    <div id="div2">there</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Try it 
Regards

Comment: Don't use the devil `eval`!!!!! For example, instead of `eval("_elem." + name + " = fn");` use `_elem[name] = fn;`