# Defining styles for elements also defined in two separate style sheets

Tags: css

I regularly work on a site where the style sheets require a full build and deploy to update, which is a big hassle and not worth it to update something basic like link styles.

I have a way I can apply my own styles through a CMS to avoid the full build and deploy, but I have to override with !important if the style is already defined in one of those sheets, or by using more specific selectors.

I don't believe there are negative consequences to using !important, though I know it is not a best practice because it can be tricky to maintain.   But here is an example I'm not sure about.  Let's say I have this bit of HTML:

```
            <p class="snaps">
                This is a bit of text followed <a class="snaps-link">by a link</a>
            </p>
```

and in one style sheet we have:

```
            .snaps {text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}
```

and in another style sheet the a element is defined like this:

```
            a { outline: none; color: #6D6E71; text-decoration: none;}
```

and I want to write a style like this, in the CMS (either through an external or internal style sheet):

```
            p.snaps a.snaps-link{color: orange; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: normal;}
```

Is there a problem with doing this? I am the only one at my company who knows anything about coding, so I don't have anyone to bounce ideas off of.  And so I come to you...interested to hear what anyone thinks.

Another issue I run into is that I am frequently asked to remove elements.  Often times the easiest way to do it is to use display: none and hide them.  I think that can have SEO penalties if I am hiding text, but are there other consequences I'm not aware of?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this CSS:

```
p.snaps a.snaps-link{color: orange; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: normal;}
```

What you're using there is called a *combinator*, and it's completely legit. [Read more about combinators here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#combinators)

Your method of `display: none;` is a fine solution. There shouldn't be any consequences to doing that that would effect you in any big negative way. If you can inject JavaScript through the CMS, you could [use it to remove the element entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element).

Comment: Thank you! This information is really helpful to me, I didn't realize I could use JavaScript to remove the elements.  Learning on the job :)