# Clear dynamically created <ul>?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looking for a cross-browser way to `clear/remove/delete` a dynamically created ul (with li-posts)-list.

created as such: `document.createElement("ul");`

Is there a truly cross-browser method implemented?

**Edit**: JQuery not allowed.

Comment: jQuery can do this? I believe [**removeChild**](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdihaqn.php) in plain JS is as "cross browser" as they come.

Comment: 'cross-browser' which browsers?

Comment: Sorry, non-Jquery. Browsers.. 'all'? The main issue is between IE-FF-Chrome, i guess.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague.. Why not jQuery?

Comment: I'm pretty comfy using JQuery, but really need to work on my 'core' javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// assuming you created your `ul` like this
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

If you just want to remove its content

```
// removing only its content
ul.innerHTML = "";
```

Or you can remove both element and content like this

```
// removing element and content
ul.parentNode.removeChild(ul);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `removeChild`

```
var createdUL=document.createElement("ul"); 
createdUL.parentNode.removeChild(ul);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems this link might be help you. But remember your question is clear to understand but you have to post some code also to check for the possibilities. Try the following link.
[JavaScript DOM remove element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element)

Answer (score 1):

You can how use [replaceChildren](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/replaceChildren) to accomplish this:

```js
ul.replaceChildren();
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery remove?

```
$("ul").remove();
```

Content remove:

```
$("ul *").remove();
```