# Setting an image src to empty

Tags: html, image, src

I would like to set an image as nothing. By doing `src=""` many people say it can cause problems to browsers:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/

so I am not sure if below can face to the same problem as setting src to empty:

```
<img id="myImage">
```

since there's no src attribute on this case.

So If I want to initially set an image to nothing, what's the best I can do?

Comment: because initially there's no image, and when process finished, i put an image depending on the process has passed or failed.

Comment: Ok, using a div and setting its background-image seems to be a good idea. But what are the differences between using img or div with background-image in terms of performance? in my case there a some images loading at the same time and they can be animated gifs, so img or div? is div back-ground compatible with animated gifs?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Best solution

Initialise the image as follows: `src="//:0"` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src): `<img id="myImage" src="//:0">`

> ***Edit**: as per the comment of Alex below, using `//:0` apparently can trigger the `onError` event of the `img`. So beware of this.*
>
> ***Edit 2**: From comment by [Drkawashima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1295378/drkawashima): As of Chrome 61 `src="//:0"` no longer seems to trigger the onError event*.

---

**Other solution**

Alternatively, you can use a very small image until you actually fill the `src` tag: [like this image](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever). With this 'very small image', you would then initialise the tag like so:

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" width="0" height="0" alt="" />`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src)

---

**Remove element from DOM**

Alternatively, if you simply don't want the element to appear in the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), just use some JavaScript:

```
var myObject = document.getElementById('myObject');
myObject.parentNode.removeChild(myObject);
```

<sub>(as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46336245/2431885), using JavaScript's `.remove()` function is not recommended, due to poor browser support in DOM 4)</sub>

Or just use some jQuery:

```
$("#myObject").remove();
```

---

Comment: do not use # as the source. for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28077004/3841049

Comment: Using "//:0" as the `src` triggers the `onError` event on the `img` (at least in Chrome as of version 57)

Comment: //:0 clearly saved my life. Did not care about the error, since is for a internal project :) I was setting the attr.src by jQuery but it always placed a display:none!important what ever I did.

Comment: @PatricePoliquin Glad to hear that. Good luck with your project.

Comment: As of Chrome 61 `src="//:0"` no longer seems to trigger the `onError` event

Comment: @Drkawashima Useful comment! Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: This shows a broken image in chrome after zooming in and out.

Answer (score 24):

Using a 1px transparent encoded image is an accepted solution (recommended by [CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/))

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="">
```

PS: Don't be confused later when DevTools shows these as network requests of zero bytes, that's just how DevTools works, all imgs are listed as network requests.

DS: `alt=""` is included because otherwise, screenreaders will read the `src` out loud

Comment: I upvoted it because it's a transparent image/gif. That is a lot more flexible than the white image supplied on the accepted answer. That's great, thanks! (you could mention it in your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hash symbol `#`. It's valid value for `src` attribute. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077004/3841049

Comment: please check the link. this method is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to set a default image if src is empty or blank

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('img').each(function () {
       if($(this).attr('src')=="") {
          $(this).attr('src', 'Images/download.jpg');
       }
   });
});
```