# Remove all the DOM elements with a specific tag name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I remove all the elements with a specific tag name using Javascript. For example, I did the following:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("center");
```

and it returned an array of all the `center` elements. How may I remove all these elements?

Coming from [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript) and [JavaScript DOM remove element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element) I know that I can loop through `els`, find the parent of each element and then remove that specific node. But is there anyother way provided by javascript. Like we can do `$('center').remove()` in jquery and it removes all the elements with `center` tag. Anything similar to that in Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id

Comment: [Yes there is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) but you still have to loop.

Comment: FWIW, the jQuery `$('center').remove()` will still loop though the nodes internally.

Comment: using pure javascript,if you need to remove certain tags,you will have to traverse the DOM.
Traversing is not possible without looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"it returned an array of all the center elements."*

Well, it returned an array-like object (a *live* NodeList or an HTMLCollection depending on the browser).

> *"How may I remove all these elements?"*

You have to loop through the list removing them one at a time as you mentioned later in your question. If you find yourself doing that a lot, encapsulate the looping inside a function so that you don't have to repeat it.

> *"we can do `$('center').remove()` in jquery and it removes all the elements with center tag. Anything similar to that in Javascript?"*

jQuery is a collection of JavaScript functions, so it can't do anything JavaScript can't do. jQuery's `.remove()` method (like most other jQuery methods) will loop internally, it just saves you having to think about it. So that comes back to what I already mentioned above, encapsulate the loop/remove code in a function so that you can use it from any part of your code.

Comment: You're welcome. More info about the list type at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName).

Answer (score 15):

With the mention that you still loop over the elements (there is no way to avoid that), you can do this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('center')).forEach(
  function(item) {
    item.remove();
    // or item.parentNode.removeChild(item); for older browsers (Edge-)
});
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/OtOyUVE/1/edit

Some notes on slice:

`document.getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an array, it returns a live list with a length
property. That is why it is needed to first convert it into an array (`Array.prototype.slice` does that for any object with the `length` property). By doing that you eliminate the problem of the list being live (gets updated when you change the DOM) and you also get the other array functions to work (like `forEach`) which have a more functional syntax for looping.

Comment: This needs more upvotes. Why use `item.parentNode.removeChild` instead of `item.remove`?

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23 The remove method is newer and not supported in older browsers. I will add it to the answer though, thanks!

Comment: Can be done more concisely today:

`document.querySelectorAll('center').forEach(item => item.remove())`