# javascript removing elements

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove such type html elements using javascipt?

```
<section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
 <div class="cd-timeline-block">
        <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-location">
            <img src="img/cd-icon-location.svg" alt="Location">
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->
        <div class="cd-timeline-content">
            <h2>Title of section 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. .</p>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
            <span class="cd-date">Feb 14</span>
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
    </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->   
</section> <!-- cd-timeline -->
```

Comment: Do you mean hashtags? Hashtags are Twitter.

Comment: sorry i was thinking about my other part of code while writing it :D

Comment: What do you want to remove?

Comment: U mean how to remove the whole `<section>...</section>` part?

Comment: i nead to remove all of it

Comment: Do you want to remove it or just hide it in DOM? So that it will not be visible in html page.

Comment: it will be better if i will be able to remove it

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var element = document.getElementById('cd-timeline');

if (element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
document.getElementById("cd-timeline").outerHTML='';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
document.getElementById('cd-timeline').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove a element by it's id use:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");

elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

If you would like to remove elements by their tag, class, etc. use:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTag("myDiv");

for(var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
     if(elems[i] && elems[i].parentElement) {
         elems[i].parentElement.removeChild(elems[i]);
     }
}
```