# How to style a DIV if the IMG inside it has broken image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Still a Newbie using Javascript.  I know something's wrong with my function code.  I just can't restructure it well.

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=IMG1" onerror="imgError(this);" />
</div>
<div class="column">
    <img src="httzp://placehold.it/200x200&text=IMG2" onerror="imgError(this);" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    parent('div.column').image.css('border','5px solid red');
    return true;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/c0wfe7wv/1/)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/c0wfe7wv/1/
ooops. sorry.  incomplete.  here's the updated one.  forgot to save.

Comment: not able to understand plz explain what do you want actually???

Comment: ok. in the second DIV i simply inserted "Z" in the http so that the image source will have an error.  And once there is an error within that image inside that particular DIV, I want to style the DIV.

thanks again.

Comment: @Flopet17 - can you save it and share your jsfiddle which is updated?
to Kat - i just added an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
function imgError(image) {
    $(image).parent('div.column').css('border','5px solid red');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c0wfe7wv/11/)

Comment: @Philcyb hey, If this answer is use full to you, Mark it as a answer.

Comment: @Kartikeya - sure. just one more added question. since I need to make this work in IE8, .remove() does not work.  is there a Javascript replacement instead of .remove()?  what i mean is, not using the $. just pure javascript.

Comment: @Philcyb..jquery versions below 2.x i.e. 1.11 and below perfectly works with ie8 also and you can easily use `.remove()` to remove dom elements but if you only need javascript then follow these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id  and if there is another question you want to ask then put a new question on SO and we will solve it .. try to refrain asking question in comments section..now mark this answer as accepted so that it will help others also..thanks...