# Can the root element HTML in the DOM be replaced in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a beginner in javascript. As mentioned in [stack overflow query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element), I can remove or create elements within the DOM. However, can I replace the root element  through javascript e.g. if I want to change an attribute of the HTML element through javascript?

Comment: Why would you need to replace the root element if you just want to change its attributes?

Comment: The title of this question should be changed since OP is asking changing attribute.

Comment: To actually change the root element (e.g. replace the whole document) you can use `document.documentElement.replaceWith(newHTML);` - this is a very rare edge case, usually you just want to change attributes of the existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking if you can modify the element, and the answer is yes.

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
html.title = "Foo"; // Set an attr on the element
```

Comment: You can just reference `document.documentElement`.  No need to `getElementsByTagName()`

Comment: True enough, I just wanted to provide a working example if the OP wanted to traverse further down the DOM and programmatically adjust other tags, like meta, for example.