# How to remove DOM element after ajax request with unobtrusive-ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, unobtrusive-ajax

In the callback function "OnSuccess",i can't get the element which i've clicked.
After click the "Del" button ,i try to remove the "tr" element which one the "Del" button in that i just clicked.how to do this?

Comment: I knew that $(selector).remove() could remove the DOM elements,but i just wanted remove it in the Callback function.
Note: not jquery ajax or get,post ,just asp.net mvc @Ajax generated with unobrusive-ajax,in that OnSuccess callback function.

Comment: Such as :
@Ajax.Actionlink("Del","actionName",new AjaxOption({OnSuccess="SuccessCallback"})
<script>
function SuccessCallback(data){
//to remove the parent tr element
}
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it using jquery:

```
$('#selector').remove();
```

> also check this out:

[JavaScript DOM remove element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element)

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of `$(this)` to get the button (or other dom element that triggered it).

Then `.closest` with the `tr` parameter to get the row.

Followed by `.remove` to remove it:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: I knew that could remove it ,but i wanna to remove it in the callback function of OnSuccess for the unobtrusive-ajax.

Comment: @developer.zheng Sorry, a quick way I can think of is to pass the id across to the action. Return it as data and if you add a parameter to your `OnSuccess` call i.e. `OnSuccess(e)` the returned data will be available. Failing that I would need to setup a test example to debug and see if I could navigate to the event. You have included no code in your example though.