# JavaScript equivalent to angularjs ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I want to remove/add element on `DOM` I just use `ng-if` and the code under it does not compile into to DOM, can I do the same using pure js? I don't want the HTML code inside my js code.

Hiding it using CSS:

```
<div id = "infoPage" style="display: none;">
```

Will still insert the element to the DOM.

**EDIT**

The condition for showing or not is based on a flag like:

```
var show = false; //or true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript DOM remove element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element)

Comment: @Weedoze No. Its about adding/removing element based on a flag.

Comment: @Rajesh - yes, my goal is that only flag will appear in js.

Comment: @Rajesh The link will explain him how to remove the child. If only have to add an `if` condition to remove it or not. What does it need more ?

Comment: You can do it with removeChild. Just add if condition, and that's it. Same thing like ngIf

Comment: @Weedoze How would you add the element again? Where will you save the element if value is false and it is removed from DOM?

Comment: @Rajesh Ok the question I linked is not complete to answer OP's question but his question is actually a mix of existing questions on SO.

Comment: @Weedoze removeChild works after the DOM loaded, so in some stage of loading the code inside gets compiled on to the DOM, not the same as `ng-if` at all.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rajesh You can store the collection of DOM elements in a variable. This solves your issue

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas ng-if does the same thing. It compiles in the DOM, then removes it. Read documentation on ng-if

Comment: Yes but is the condition is false?`If the expression is falsy then the element is removed from the DOM tree. If it is truthy a copy of the compiled element is added to the DOM tree.` so if I understant right only true flag will make it compield. Posting a code based on the answers.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas Hope my answer helps in some way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea:

- Create an object that holds reference of currentElement and its parent (*so you know where to add*).
- Create a clone of current element as you want to add same element after its removed.
- Create a property using `Object.defineProperty`. This way you can have your own setter and you can observe changes over it.
- To toggle element, check

  - If value is true, you have to add element. But check if same element is already available or not to avoid duplication.
  - If false, remove element.

```js
var CustomNGIf = function(element, callback, propertyName) {
  var _value = null;

  // Create copies of elements do that you can store/use it in future 
  this.parent = element.parentNode;
  this.element = element;
  this.clone = null;

  // Create a property that is supposed to be watched
  Object.defineProperty(this, propertyName, {
    get: function() {
      return _value;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      // If same value is passed, do nothing.
      if (_value === value) return;
      _value = !!value;
      this.handleChange(_value);
    }
  });

  this.handleChange = function(value) {
    this.clone = this.element.cloneNode(true);
    if (_value) {
      var index = Array.from(this.parent.children).indexOf(this.element);

      // Check if element is already existing or not.
      // This can happen if some code breaks before deleting node.
      if (index >= 0) return;
      this.element = this.clone.cloneNode(true);
      this.parent.appendChild(this.element);
    } else {
      this.element.remove();
    }

    // For any special handling
    callback && callback();
  }
}

var div = document.getElementById('infoPage');
const propName = 'value';
var obj = new CustomNGIf(div, function() {
  console.log("change")
}, propName);

var count = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  obj[propName] = count++ % 2;
  if (count >= 10) {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 2000)
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div id="infoPage"> test </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: **Note:** If you think something is wrong with the answer please share your feedback along with your vote. :-)