# This is my script for adding div dynamically, i require a function to remove dynamically created div

Tags: javascript

It creates a div dynamically,for that i have used clone function,now i want to remove the div which is dynamically created using javascript.Thanks in advance.

```js
<script>
$(function(){
  var target = "collapsible_obj1_";
  var i = 1;
  
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    $(".parent_colapse1:last").clone(true).insertAfter(".parent_colapse1:last");        
    $(".parent_colapse1:last > button").attr("data-target", "#"+target+i);
    $(".parent_colapse1:last .collapse").attr("id", target+i);
    i++;
  });
  $(document).on("click",".button1",function(){
     alert();
  });
  
});
   
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript DOM remove element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element)

Comment: post your HTML too.