# How to remove added item from a list?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JS and I decided to make a real app so that I can learn while I'm doing some stuff. I'm trying to make a TODO list app, I made the adding items but I can't figure out how to remove items when they got clicked.

Here's the code iteself:

MY TODO'S

```
    <input id= "input" class="form-control" placeholder="Add items to your TODO list." type="text">

    <button id="button" class="button btn btn-primary btn-block">Add</button>

    <div class="items">
        <ul id= "listGroup" class="list-group">
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- JS Items !-->
</div> <!-- End Div -->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button")

button1.addEventListener("click", addItem)

function addItem() {

    let item = document.getElementById("input").value
    let add = document.getElementById("listGroup")

    let makeLi = document.createElement("li")
    let makeText = document.createTextNode(item)
    makeLi.className += "list-group-item"

    let icon = document.createElement("i")
    icon.className += "fa fa-times"

    add.appendChild(makeLi).appendChild(makeText)
}

function revomeItem() {
}
```

Comment: You should use semicolons, also you spelt remove wrong in your function name

Comment: Dude, its not the problem, i dont know how to remove the items that i added.

Comment: I know... I was just pointing it out, no need to be so hostile to someone looking to help you

Comment: Oh, you got me wrong, i wasnt trying to offense you in any way. :)

Comment: When you add an item, why not add an "x" or "remove" tag to that item, so then you can target that x/remove element in an event listener that can remove the todo item or mark it as finished.

Comment: I dont know how to do that, as i said im still learning i hope i'll be able to someday :)

Comment: If you want someone else to help you, you should take care of your question, paying attention to the grammar and posting a code section as ordered as you can. This way, the other users don't wast more time that it needs to understand your issue. And... yes, the semicolons :)  You have several questions with negative score... maybe you should read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript DOM remove element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div-01")
    div1.addEventListener("click", removeItem);
    function removeItem(e){
        e.target.remove();
    }
```

This should work..

Comment: That element should i pick with getElementById exactly can you explain?
Its the listGroup, i found it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
makeLi.onclick = function(){
 this.remove();
};
```