# Safely / completely remove element from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this:

```
let elem = document.querySelector('#some-element');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

seems superfluous...is there not a method on element to remove itself from the DOM?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id

Comment: To be precise, simple way of doing what you ask for - `ChildNode.remove()` - is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380133/1229023)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27574326/2055998

Comment: Yes, even better answer.