# How to remove the parent element without going to parentNode?

Tags: javascript, dom

Im just wondering in order to remove a parent, you need to go to its parentNode. such as:

```
 div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

What happens if div has no parents? How can you remove div without going to its parents?

Comment: Every `<div>` will have at least on parent: `<body>`

Comment: True that, but I was just wondering if in some weird case it doesnt. or say you want to remove <body> how would you do that?

Comment: @RandyCasburn, really, every element will have at least one parent: `<html>`.

Comment: There _is_ an element [`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method, but it has zero IE support.  Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element)

Comment: @zero298 - you are incorrect my friend. Every browser will automatically insert the `<body>` element if an errant developer does not do it themselves. This is much like when every `<table>` has a `<tbody>` element whether you put it there or not.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Interesting, and `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].parent;` returns `undefined`.  Good note.

Comment: @zero298 - That was not the OPs question. the question was about a '<div>' not the document body - stop being obtuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a div element doesn't have parent, there is no place to remove this div from, so your div element doesn't exist in the page.
It's safe to use `div.parentNode.removeChild(div);` because if the div element doesn't have a parent, it is already removed, or just never added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

No need to go to the parent. Just use `remove`.

```
div.remove();
```

That will remove the exact node.

This is not supported in older browsers so you would need a polyfill for them as defined on this page: http://devdocs.io/dom/childnode/remove