# How to use JavaScript get and set for polyfill

Tags: javascript, get, dataset, set, polyfills

I'm trying to figure out how to make a polyfill for [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset) and I think I need to use [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get) and [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/set) to define the function. How would the syntax of get/set be when trying to add them to `Element.prototype`? The examples on MDN shows a local variable, but how do you use them to add to `Element.prototype`?

```
Object.defineProperty {Element.prototype, "dataset", 
   get: function() { /* return value */ }
 , set: function(newVal) { /* set somehow w/ setAttribute or jQuery */ }
}
```

I'd like to either route the getter/setter methods to [$.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) the example above I just related them to [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) or (better) the native `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.
There is one [polyfill for dataset here](https://github.com/adalgiso/html5-dataset/blob/master/html5-dataset.js) but it only supports standards-compliant browsers (not IE8 or less). I want to do one the avoids the use of `__defineGetter__` (I think that's the issue in IE8). I think [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) may be the appropriate method, and I can use the [ES5 Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) to polyfill that. How would I use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty maybe

Comment: I think `defineProperty` is the way. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Object.defineProperty` works where available. I've [made such a polyfill](https://gist.github.com/4093766#file_html5_dataset.js) based on Eli Grey's original, enhancing a little bit by avoiding globals/non-standard prototype overriding and to work properly with CamelCasing (and utilizing his Xccessors polyfill where `defineProperty` support is lacking).

**Update:** Although it doesn't matter for you in this case, I might mention that the `defineProperty` polyfill will only work in IE8 on DOM objects. And it will not work before IE8 because one cannot override the DOM prototypes before then--unless you really want to get your hands dirty and [build your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696794/271577), but doing it thoroughly would be a vast task. Also, the `dataset` polyfills (mine and the original) currently only work *in a polyfill, standard-friendly manner* to read in properties from `Element.prototype.getAttribute()` and work from there. `Element.prototype.getAttribute` would also need polyfilling in order to ensure it was getting the latest dataset-updated version, etc.