# How to reference the caller object ("this") using attachEvent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, this

Using the method `.attachEvent()` in IE, how can I reference the caller object (the element that triggered the event) with **`this`**? In *normal* browsers, using `.addEventListener`, the var `this` points to the element, while in IE it points to the **`window`** object.

I need it to work with the following code:

```
var element = //the element, doesn't matter how it is obtained
element.addAnEvent = function(name, funct){
   if(element.addEventListener) // Works in NORMAL browsers...
   else if(element.attachEvent){
     element.attachEvent("on"+name, funct);
     //where the value of "this" in funct should point to "element"
   }
}
```

I just made that code up, it's not *exactly* the same as my code, but if it works with it then it works with me!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [this quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html#link6) with regard to `attachEvent`:

> 1. Events always bubble, no capturing possibility.
> 2. The event handling function is referenced, not copied, **so the this keyword always refers to the window and is completely useless**.
>
> The result of these two weaknesses is that when an event bubbles up it is impossible to know which HTML element currently handles the event. I explain this problem more fully on the Event order page.
>
> Since the Microsoft event adding model is only supported by Explorer 5 and higher on Windows, it cannot be used for cross–browser scripts. But even for Explorer–on–Windows only applications it’s best not to use it, since the bubbling problem can be quite nasty in complex applications.

I haven't tested it, but a possible workaround may be to wrap the handler in an anonymous function that calls your handler via `funct.call()`.

```
else if(element.attachEvent){
   element.attachEvent("on"+name, function(){ funct.call( element ) });
}
```

My apologies for the untested solution. I don't like doing that, but can't easily get to IE right now.

Comment: so instead of using it, should I use the classic way `element.onevent=function`? (Ex. `element.onmouseup`...)

Comment: @JCOC611: Just updated my answer. My potential code solution was backward the first time. If that doesn't work, then yes, I'd think that the classic way would be a fallback.

Comment: I tried that before, but I just figured out what I did wrong. Thanks a lot! Patrick ftw!!! XD

Comment: @JCOC611: You're welcome, but I'm a little confused about the reason why you have `addAnEvent` function attached directly to the `element`. I'd think it would be more useful to pass the element into a separate function as a third parameter. Since my solution refers to the `element` variable, it may fail. If you're calling it like `element.addAnEvent( 'click', thefunc )`, then you should change the solution above to `funct.call( this )`. Still, I'd consider a different approach.

Comment: don't worry, I think I know what I'm doing lol, using "this" in the `call` method instead of a variable was what I did wrong because in IE "this" in the anonymous function also references the window object

Comment: @JCOC611: Ah yes, good point. You'd need to reference it first. Anyway, I won't worry too much. ;o)

Answer (score 10):

If you're in IE, you can get the "caller" object, as you call it, by accessing `window.event.srcElement` within the event handler function.  This object is normally referred to as the event *target* or *source*.

```
var funct = function(event) {
    if ( !event ) {
        event = window.event;
    }

    var callerElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    // Do stuff
};
```

This code is untested, but should set you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Bind it. Well, you can't use `Function.prototype.bind` that gets added in javascript 1.8.5, but you can use closure and `Function.prototype.apply`.

```
var element = //the element, doesn't matter how it is obtained
element.addAnEvent = function(name, funct){
   if(element.addEventListener) // Works in NORMAL browsers...
     //...
   else if(element.attachEvent){
     element.attachEvent("on"+name, function() {
       //call funct with 'this' == 'element'
       return funct.apply(element, arguments);
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: D'oh how did I miss that Patric had answered it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to extend the [`Element` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element) , *through the prototype chain*, instead of adding your method to each element you want to add events to (*works with all browsers*)..

```
Element.prototype.addAnEvent = function(name, funct){
   if(this.addEventListener) // Works in NORMAL browsers...
   {
     this.addEventListener(name,funct, false);
   }
   else if(this.attachEvent){
     var _this = this;
     this.attachEvent("on"+name, function(){funct.apply(_this);});
     //where the value of "this" in funct should point to "element"
   }
};
```

This way it will work for all your current and future elements (*and you only have to run it once*).

Comment: Yea I know of JS prototyping. Still, my code doesn't require prototyping. I'm doing an equivalent of jQuery's `$()` function. Besides, I bet prototyping isn't fully cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @JCOC, the above code is tested in IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera.. But i am just suggesting an alternative.. You know the details and you can decide what is best for your case :)

Comment: @Tim, indeed.. IT is for IE8+, and in general it is extending the DOM object through the prototype chain is [frowned upon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592815/is-there-really-no-way-to-expose-the-prototype-of-a-html-element-in-ie-8/)