# How to get the element clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you check to see which item was clicked in the document, given this code?

```
if ( document.addEventListener && document.attachEvent && document.fireEvent ) {
    document.attachEvent( "onclick", function() {
     // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `attachEvent` when `addEventListener` is available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent

Comment: @Quentin This was from the Jquery source code, I don't know why they used these two together, anyone have an answer to Quentin's question?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
// using e.srcElement or event.srcElement
```

try this :) 
and see this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

```
if (document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement);
    });
} else if (document.attachEvent) {    
    document.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement);
    });
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to know which element was clicked at the time the event is fired, and your answer doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: `srcElement` is old and mostly a microsoft implementation, I'd rather use `event.target` when available. `var target = event.target || event.srcElement;` [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5301667/1331430). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target).

Comment: No problem, also the first listener handler (`addEventListener`)'s function should use `e.target` I guess, ugh now even my head is spinning with these hacks for older versions of IE.

Comment: This may be a little redundant but should make it bulletproof: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nVj8z/). Thankfully nowadays there's jQuery to take care of handlers binding..

Comment: `event` is undefined. Did you mean to write `function(event)` instead of `function(e)`?

Comment: `event`  is not defined, it should be `function( event )`

Comment: In the old IE browser, the 'event' object exists as a property of the global 'window' object.
Therefore, when 'event' is called (if document.attachEvent exists), 'event' is defined in global namespace.

Comment: dude, thats a cool stuff, thanks!