# Retrieve the ID of the form or button that addEventListener answered.

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have 30 submit buttons on this page and need to identify the ID of the DOM that sent the submit.  This code is working and all I need now is to scoop up where the submit came from.   The console.log("id=" + this.id); is showing id=undefined.

```
<form id="offspringpicfrm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="offspringpicfile" type="file" name="files[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="offspringpicsubmit" >
</form>

const url = 'pedigree_pic_upload.php';
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("id=" + this.id);

const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
const formData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i];

    formData.append('files[]', file);
}

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

});

Comment: Don't use an arrow function as event handler if you want `this` to refer to the DOM element.

Comment: probably you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741070/js-how-to-get-the-element-clicked-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `e.target` to get information about the dom element:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("id=" + e.target.id);
 })
```

```html
<form id="offspringpicfrm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="offspringpicsubmit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks!!!!  Thought I tried that but missed it.  Wish I could give bonus points for being so fast.