# Finding a javascript "this" keyword substitute for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a basic javascript drop-down menu, using addEventListener and attachEvent to handle the click and mouse functions. The function called by the click event, subOpen, uses the javascript "this" keyword to get the id of the clicked element.

Sample of adding the event:

```
//add event listeners to menuitems
for (var i=0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
    if (menuitems[i].addEventListener) {
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('click', subOpen, false);    
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('mouseout', closeTimer, false);
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('mouseover', cancelTimer, false);
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('selectstart', menucursorselect, false);
    } else if (menuitems[i].attachEvent) {
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onclick', subOpen);    
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onmouseout', closeTimer);
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onmouseover', cancelTimer);
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onselectstart', menucursorselect);    
    }
}
```

Sample of the subOpen function using "this" keyword:

```
function subOpen() {
cancelTimer(); //stops the close timer  

if (submenudisplay) {
    document.getElementById(submenudisplay).style.display = "none";
    activeSubMenu = false;
}
var curMenuId = this.id;
var curSubMenuId = this.id + "submenu";

if (curSubMenuId) {
    document.getElementById(curSubMenuId).style.display = "block";
    activeSubMenu = true;   
}

submenudisplay = curSubMenuId;
```

Now, everything is working in all the browsers I've tested except for the earlier versions of Internet Explorer. With older versions of IE, the debugger is flagging "this.id" as undefined, so it doesn't know which submenu to open. I did some research and found out that old IE doesn't copy the function when it attaches an event, but references it, so there's no way I can capture any useful data with the "this" keyword.

I was wondering if there was a different keyword or function I could use to accomplish the same thing that works with the older versions of IE.

Full version of my test code can be found [here](http://www.asmithspace.net/testing/menutest.html):

Comment: I hate to suggest big scary frameworks, but that's the kind of thing jQuery excels at doing. It's really convenient and it handles Internet Explorer well enough.

Comment: I would describe jQuery as _warm and fuzzy_ as opposed to _big and scary_.  In this day and age, it's almost understood that you use jQuery when using JavaScript.

Comment: @user1689607 - Which part is nonsense?  _"Warm and fuzzy"_ or _"Understood that it's used"_?  I think the first statement is pretty solid.  The second is admittedly questionable...

Comment: Sorry, mainly the latter, though I really don't see jQuery as either big and scary or warm and fuzzy. It's just another code library to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference the caller object ("this") using attachEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery to bind the events instead of calling the `addEventListener` and `attachEvents` functions directly. jQuery will work around these cross-browser compatibilities issues.

So my answer here is not to do it. But in case you do it, know that the function called by internet explorer has no `this` keyword by default. In order to access the element you have to look for the element in `window.event.srcElement`. On W3C compatible browsers you can use `this` or `event.target`. You can use the function `_addEventListener` bellow as cross-browser version of the W3C function.

```
var _addEventListener = function (obj, evt, ofnc, bubble) {
    var fnc = function (event) {
        if (!event || !event.target) {
            event = window.event;
            event.target = event.srcElement;
        }
        return ofnc.call(obj, event);
    };
    // W3C model
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, ofnc, !!bubble);
        return true;
    }
    // M$ft model
    else {
        return obj.attachEvent('on' + evt, fnc);
    }
};
```

```
//add event listeners to menuitems
for (var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
    _addEventListener(menuitems[i], 'click', subOpen, false);
    _addEventListener(menuitems[i], 'mouseout', closeTimer, false);
    _addEventListener(menuitems[i], 'mouseover', cancelTimer, false);
    _addEventListener(menuitems[i], 'selectstart', menucursorselect, false);
}​
```

Comment: @jahroy: It's not at all. And this answer looks like it was plagiarized from elsewhere on the internet. I can find identical code examples, right down to the `// M$ft model` code comment.

Comment: @user1689607 it's actually copied and simplified from a piece of my own code. Original [here](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas/blob/master/src/helpers.js).

Comment: Fair enough. My apologies for the accusation. But then may I ask why you pass `fnc` to `addEventListener` instead of `ofnc`? If `addEventListener` is supported, the event object fixes would seem unnecessary.

Comment: That's actually a good feedback. I wrote this function over a year ago and never thought about it. Thanks @user1689607

Comment: In that case, you may also want to move the handler wrapper function to the `else` so that you're not unnecessarily creating the function. It could be that modern implementations will optimize it away anyway, but just in case...

Comment: Thank you Eduardo, this is just what I was looking for!
I've used jQuery sparingly in the recent past; still don't understand much of the syntax. I'll have to get in more practice so I can use it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function that invokes your handler and sets the `this` value manually.

Here I created a `bindHandler` function that receives the element and the handler, and returns a new handler that invokes the original handler with the element as the `this` value.

It also passes the `window.event` object to the original handler to gain that consistency as well.

```
for (var i=0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
    if (menuitems[i].addEventListener) {
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('click', subOpen, false); 
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('mouseout', closeTimer, false);
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('mouseover', cancelTimer, false);
        menuitems[i].addEventListener('selectstart', menucursorselect, false);
    } else if (menuitems[i].attachEvent) {
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onclick', bindHandler(menuitems[i], subOpen));   
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onmouseout', bindHandler(menuitems[i], closeTimer));
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onmouseover', bindHandler(menuitems[i], cancelTimer));
        menuitems[i].attachEvent('onselectstart', bindHandler(menuitems[i], menucursorselect));  
    }
}

function bindHandler(elem, handler) {
    return function() {
        return handler.call(elem, window.event);
    };
}
```

---

FWIW, I'd create a single binding function that takes care of this for you in order to reduce some of the repetitious code.

```
for (var i=0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
    bindHandler(menuitems[i], 'click', subOpen);
    bindHandler(menuitems[i], 'mouseout', closeTimer);
    bindHandler(menuitems[i], 'mouseover', cancelTimer);
    bindHandler(menuitems[i], 'selectstart', menucursorselect);
}

function bindHandler(elem, type, handler) {
    if (elem.addEventListener)
        elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent)
        elem.attachEvent("on" + type,  function() {
            return handler.call(elem, window.event);
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addHandler(elem, type, handler) {
    elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
}
if (!document.addEventListener)
    addHandler = function(elem, type, handler) {
        elem.attachEvent('on'+type, function() {
            handler.call(elem, window.event);
        });
    };
```

Then use

```
for (var i=0; i<menuitems.length; i++) {
    addHandler(menuitems[i], 'click', subOpen);
    addHandler(menuitems[i], 'mouseout', closeTimer);
    addHandler(menuitems[i], 'mouseover', cancelTimer);
    addHandler(menuitems[i], 'selectstart', menucursorselect);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The actual "event" is passed to the handling function, and you can get the element from the event.

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventtargetsrcelement.htm

Comment: `srcElement` is not necessarily the same as the desired `this` value.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't mean that srcElement can directly replace this. It gives you enough to solve the problem at hand.