# JavaScript IE8 "this" is always "object window"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference the caller object (“this”) using attachEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent)

I'm perplexed by the behavior of "this" in older versions of IE.

alert(this); always returns [Object Window]. I realize the answer is "use JQuery", but unfortunately I am not allowed to do so.

I have multiple forms on a page, which are generated by a cgi script.

The problem arises when I attempt to place a listener on an input button. The listener will do some some bounds checking, then submit the form.

```
 if (inputs[b].name === "Submit") {
     form = document.forms[f];
     form.attachEvent("onclick", function () {
         submit_valid();
     });
 }
```

I'm expecting to be able to be able to submit the form from "submit_valid".

```
function submit_valid (form) {
    alert(this);
    this.submit();
}
```

debugger shows "Object doesn't support this property or method", so obviously "this" is not doing what I think it should be doing. :-)

Is "this" useful at all in <= IE8? What should I do to submit the form?

Comment: epascarello is correct, the question is adequately answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent

Answer (score -1):

it is ie version independent

when u call submit_valid() this way its context will always be the window object
u can change a functions context in two ways:

```
form.attachEvent("onclick", function () { submit_valid.apply(this); });
```

or

```
form.attachEvent("onclick", function () { submit_valid.call(this); });
```

this way the context of the function will be the form itself, on which u clicked
if u want to understand it deeper i would recommend this article for reading http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: what is the problem with this answer?

Comment: You're missing one major point in the question. The `.attachEvent` method is used to assign the handler, which means `this` is not the `form`.

Comment: form.attachEvent("onclick", function () {
    submit_valid.apply(this);
}); => i think it was obvious, then ill modify my answer to be more understandable

Comment: Again, `this` is not a reference to the `form` element.

Comment: by default the attached function will be evaluated on the context of the matched element...it is the same as addEventListener just in IE...just try it out in your browser before downvoting

Comment: You are simply wrong. I'm not telling you this for fun. I'm telling you this because it's correct. Anyone who has real experience working with `.attachEvent` knows it is not the same. If you read the linked [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent), it's right there for you. If you read the [quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html#link6) linked from that question, it's there as well. When binding handlers with `.attachEvent`, the `this` value of the handler will *not* be the element.

Answer (score -1):

In the submit_valid function you're calling this.submit which is undefined.  What you need to do is call form.submit();

```
function submit_valid (form) {

    form.submit();
}
```

and in the event handler creation attach submit_valid as the handler.

```
form.attachEvent("onclick", submit_valid);
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work at all, since the attatchEvent is not passing the "form" value to submit_valid.