# IE event callback object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, event-handling, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference the caller object (“this”) using attachEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent)

**This is not an exact duplicate. See my answer below as compared to the supposed duplicate!**

I may be WAY off on my terminology, so please feel free to correct me. Perhaps this is why I cannot seem to find anything relevant. No libraries, *please*.

I have an event handler, which invokes a callback function. Fancy, right? In IE<9 the `this` object in the handler is the window. I don't know why, or how to access the correct object.

```
if (document.addEventListener){
    element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
} else {
    element.attachEvent('on' +event, callback);
}
```

This part **DOES WORK**.

This part doesn't:

```
function callback(event){
    console.log(this);
}
```

`this` in IE is returning `[object Window]`, whereas it returns the element that called the `callback` function in every other browser. This is cut down significantly from my full script, but this should be everything that's relevant.

**EDIT**

This link provided by @metadings 
[How to reference the caller object ("this") using attachEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent) is very close. However, there are still two issues.

1) I need to get both the `event object` and the `DOM element` calling this function.

2) This event is handled delegation style: there may be child DOM elements firing the event, meaning `event.target` is not necessarily (and in my case, not typically) the element with the listener.

Comment: @metadings your link seems close, but I'm still lost as how to implement it in my scenario. Been trying though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, closure was the right way to go. Here's the answer for the scenario above:

```
(function(element, event){
    element.attachEvent(
        'on' + event, 
        function(e){
            callback(e, element);
        }
    );
})(element, event);
```

That does it! callback receives `e` as the `event object` and `element` as the `DOM object` that fired the listener (not necessarily the event target).

Then in callback:

```
function callback(event, obj){
    obj = obj || this;
    console.log(event, obj);
}
```

Trying with the anonymous function and .call, as suggested in the link, made `this` inside `callback()` the `event object`, which wasn't working out.

Comment: This is also very useful for custom or faking event triggers, as a custom-built object could be passed in to `callback()` as `event` with keys such as target, and `obj` can be the selected element to call on. What you don't see, and why I need the element that's firing the callback, is that there are properties on that element storing instructions for its child elements' events.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close this, but seems like you are missing the arguments, so something like this

```
element.attachEvent("on"+event, function(){ callback.apply( element, arguments ); });
```

Comment: Please reconsider your close vote. This is not an exact duplicate.