# Javascript dropdown menu not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I've got a dropdown menu that I'm having trouble to get to work in Internet Explorer. It's working fine with Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't do anything in Internet Explorer. And I prefer to keep all my javascript in my separate document javascript.js as well as I don't want to work with a library. 
The HTML code I'm using is this:

```
<div id="sidemeny-container">
<div class="sidemenu-maincat">
    <img src="cat1.jpg" alt="cat1" />
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat1.html"> - Subcat 1 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2.html"> - Subcat 2 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat3.html"> - Subcat 3 </a>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="sidemenu-maincat">
    <img src="cat2.jpg" alt="cat2" />
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2-1.html"> - Subcat 2-1 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2-2.html"> - Subcat 2-2 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2-3.html"> - Subcat 2-3 </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
#sidemeny-container {
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid; 
    height: auto;
    width: 153px;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;

}

.sidemenu-maincat {
    border-top: 1px #000 solid;
    border-right: 1px #000000 solid;
    width:148px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.sidemenu-subcat.hidden {
    display:none;
    width:148px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

And the javascript, which I have in a separate .js document:

```
    function initiate()
    {

  if (document.getElementsByClassName)
    {
        var sideMenuOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-maincat');
        for (var i = 0; i < sideMenuOptions.length; i++) {
            sideMenuOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                var subMenuItems = this.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-subcat');
                for (var s = 0; s < subMenuItems.length; s++) {
                    var subItem = subMenuItems[s];
                    if (subItem.offsetWidth === 0 && subItem.offsetHeight === 0) {
                        subItem.className = 'sidemenu-subcat';
                    } else {
                        subItem.className = subItem.className + ' hidden';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var sideMenuOptions = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i = 0; i < sideMenuOptions.length; i++) {
            if (sideMenuOptions[i].className == 'sidemenu-maincat')
            {
                sideMenuOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var subMenuItems = this.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-subcat');
                    for (var s = 0; s < subMenuItems.length; s++) {
                        var subItem = subMenuItems[s];
                        if (subItem.offsetWidth === 0 && subItem.offsetHeight === 0) {
                            subItem.className = 'sidemenu-subcat';
                        } else {
                            subItem.className = subItem.className + ' hidden';
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    }

    window.onload = initiate;
```

Comment: Press F12 to bring up the developer tools and press "Start debugging" on the script tab then rerun your code. Are there any errors? IE likes to silently fail unless you tell it you want to know.

Comment: @Plynx It says "Object doesn't support this propery or method" and marks up from the line that starts `sideMenuOptions[i]` and the rest of the script.

Comment: What version of IE is this? IE 8 and less did not support `addEventListener`.

Comment: It's IE 8. How can I work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine on IE9 & IE10. However, previous versions do not support `addEventListener`, and the `attachEvent` method [does not supply a `currentTarget` property](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). For this reason, the only way to determine the calling object is to replace the `this` reference [via prototyping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590302/1170489) (or use a framework).

Another problem with your code is that IE8 does not support `getElementsByClassName()`. While your code tests for this, the fallback tries to use it again to instantiate `subMenuItems`. A better approach would be to use [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which works in IE8 and up and would allow you to avoid duplicated code.

Complete example:

```
Element.prototype.addAnEvent = function(name, funct) {
    if (this.addEventListener) {
        this.addEventListener(name, funct, false);
    } else if (this.attachEvent) {
        var _this = this;
        this.attachEvent("on" + name, function() {
            funct.apply(_this);
            // where the value of "this" in funct should point to "element"
        });
    }
};

function initiate() {
    var sideMenuOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.sidemenu-maincat');
    for (var i = 0; i < sideMenuOptions.length; i++) {
        sideMenuOptions[i].addAnEvent('click', function() {
            openSubmenu(this);
        });
    }
}

function openSubmenu(element) {
    var subMenuItems = element.querySelectorAll('.sidemenu-subcat');
    for (var s = 0; s < subMenuItems.length; s++) {
        var subItem = subMenuItems[s];
        if (subItem.offsetWidth === 0 && subItem.offsetHeight === 0) {
            subItem.className = 'sidemenu-subcat';
        } else {
             subItem.className = subItem.className + ' hidden';
        }
    }
}

window.onload = initiate;
```

Comment: So I just put this in front of my line of code with the `addEventListener`? I'm quite new with javascript and I don't fully understand all of this code.

Comment: This does work, but it always open the 2nd submenu i.e. the options that comes up is always `Subcat 2-1 Subcat 2-2 Subcat 2-3`

Comment: Sorry about that. The element reference was being replaced on each loop iteration. I updated my answer to fix this by setting the element to the event source.

Comment: It's working for me in IE8+. Are you getting any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Humm... I works for me when I click the actual div but not when I click the picture that is inside the div. I will try it out with my full code and see how it works there. EDIT: It's the same there, it works when the picture is not click but the div.

Comment: Is this due to the fact that `document.querySelectorAll('.sidemenu-maincat')` is only selecting the divs and the pictures is layered on top of the div making them "cover" up the div making some parts not clickable?

Comment: I noticed that if you add `onclick="openSubmenu(this)"` to a sidemenu-maincat div, clicking the image works properly in IE8.

Comment: Yes, this seems to solve all the issues. Though I would like to have all my javascripts in the separate document I'm using for them. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I figured out the problem. `event.srcElement` returns the source of the event, rather than the element the event was handled on (in your case, it would return the image if that's what you clicked). Since `attachEvent` doesn't have a `currentTarget` property, the only way to determine the calling object is to replace the `this` reference via prototyping. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot man. It's so damn complicated without library and with IE being so crappy -.-

Answer (score 0):

Most developers answer this challenge by using a robust polyfill, such as JQuery, that handles cross-browser compatibility issues like this for you. It's very trying to keep up with all the cross-browser issues yourself!

If you're interested, you can include JQuery in your source and replace

```
sideMenuOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
```

with

```
$(sideMenuOptions[i]).on("click", function() {
```

That should get you started.

Comment: I don't to use any library

Comment: @Benji No problem! At least now you know what the problem is. Each time you use a function not supported by IE, you'll need to branch into both ways of doing it.

Comment: Yeah.. Only problem is I'm really struggling on how to solve it by doing that at the moment.

Comment: @Benji That's because it's hard! It's finicky and error prone and even experienced developers are likely to run into problems. That's why we mostly use libraries that have sorted all this out. Who wants to remember several ways of doing each simple thing? If you want to try your hand at it, every time you reach an error in IE, wrap that statement with an `if (/*whatever the function name is*/)` to see if it exists. If it does exist, use it. If it doesn't, in your `else` clause, do it the IE way. The sites http://quirksmode.org/ and http://caniuse.com/ have all the compatibility tables.