# IE: onclick function doesn't work with 'this'

Tags: javascript, html, css

OK, so I have a strange JS function problem for IE versions 8 and below. (who'd have guessed)

there's this function defined in the 'script' section of my page, it's supposed to change the background color of a node element on click:

```
function highlight(){
    if (this.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(163, 167, 334)"){
        this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(163, 167, 334)";
    }
}
```

basically, it's saying 'if it's not the given backgroundColor, make it that backgroundColor.'

In order to evoke the method, the same 'script' tag also contains:

```
button.attachEvent('onmousedown', highlight);
```

for some reason, I continually get the following error in the >IE9's developer tools console (running ie9 in compatibility mode as 'ie8'):

> SCRIPT5007:unable to get value of the property 'backgroundColor':
>   object is null or undefined

I'm using 'attachEvent' in IE8 in the same way I'm using 'addEventListener' in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9. Unfortunately it seems to not behave in quite the same way.

I need this because my client insists on using IE8.

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT/SOLUTION FOUND: The problem was found. Highlight function references 'this'. When attachEvent fires it always understands 'this' as meaning 'the browser window', NOT the object that receives the action. To circumvent this problem, there are two ways:

element.onevent = function;
(in my case: button.onclick = highlight)

element[onevent] = function;
(in my case: button[onclick] = highlight)

Regarding the second variant, it's a bonus thing discovered (keeping this here for anyone stumbling). I'll just share it here:
a click event can actually be triggered by writing obj[onclick] = func. (in my case that was: "button[onclick] = highlight;" this is useful because it allows 'passing in' an event's name when necessary.

---

Thanks everyone for your help! Case closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference the caller object ("this") using attachEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590122/how-to-reference-the-caller-object-this-using-attachevent)

Comment: I highly advise frameworks like jQuery to alleviate cross-browser issues.

Comment: Hello, Barmar, the link you provided isn't the exact same problem. HOWEVER one of the comments in that link led me to discover the actual issue. The issue was that the 'attachEvent' discovers only the 'window' object when using 'this' rendering it essentially useless, an alternative was found. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably going to want to go with feature detection

```
if (button.addEventListener){
 button.addEventListener( 'onmousedown', highlight, false );
}else if (button.attachEvent) {
 button.attachEvent( 'onmousedown', highlight );
}
```

This should properly register the event giving access to `this`. However, if `this` is still undefined, you may need to access the `event` object in ie.

```
function highlight(ev){
 if( typeof(ev) == "undefined" ){
  ev = window.event;
 }
 var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
 if (target.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(163, 167, 334)"{
  target.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(163, 167, 334)";
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello, indeed I actually have feature detection that works in a similar manner implemented (if this doesn't work then do this). With a similar syntax (the difference being that the statements are switched and the first one is negative as in "if addEventListener doesn't exist") 

but I'll try the second thing and update you if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly an odd scope-issue. Consider declaring a variable to access instead of `this` (difficult to show in practice  when we dont know the markup)  :

```
var hl = document.getElementById('highlight');
```

and

```
function highlight(){
  if (hl.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(163, 167, 334)"{
    hl.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(163, 167, 334)";
  }
}
```

`this.style.backgroundColor` are refering to the context, your function. And that function does not have a `style.backgroundColor`, but the element you attach to that function, by `onmousedown` probably has. Another solution is to do :

```
document.getElementById('theElementInQuestion').onmousedown = function() {
  if (this.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(163, 167, 334)"{
    this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(163, 167, 334)";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use JQuery for this as it has excellent cross browser support. I've using $("#button") which finds an element with id="button" but you could use class=".buttonClass" if you wanted to bind more elements at one time.

```
$("#button").click(highlight);

function highlight() {
    if (this.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(163, 167, 334)") {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(163, 167, 334)";
    }
};
```

I've tested this in several browsers including IE8 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function highlight(){
if (this.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(163, 167, 334)"{
    this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(163, 167, 334)";
}}
```

You are missing a ")" to close the if's condition.

Comment: ah yes, sorry about that, that was sloppiness on my side when copying the code. Fixed.