# How do I add JavaScript functions to DOM objects w/o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, prototype

How do I do something like the following, but only for DOM objects, not all objects:

```
Object.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Please use only pure JavaScript, no jQuery or other third-party libraries.

Also, please comment on your solution's standards & cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: You should use jQuery, or another library. If you dont' do this, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm the biggest proponent of jQuery you'll find, but even I won't say something like that. Doing it "wrong"? No. Very probably doing it wrong and in a more convoluted way? Almost definitely. Almost.

Comment: No. You're doing it wrong. I don't build web-apps with assembly, and I don't build anything that touches the DOM without a framework/library.

Comment: For IE compatibility, you'll have to use a wrapper object or some other inventive technique. In the end, <your favorite library here> probably does this, so unless you're doing this for learning, it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @Stefan: Don't be so dogmatic. DOM is not that hard, even allowing for browser differences, and doing without jQuery or equivalent is perfectly viable if you know what you're doing. As for the comparison between assembly and... what? JavaScript? ... that's just a bit silly.

Comment: See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592815/is-there-really-no-way-to-expose-the-prototype-of-a-html-element-in-ie-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elements in the DOM use `HTMLElement` as their prototype - so in an ideal world you would just add to this.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
};
```

BUT: This doesn't work in IE, so no go I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested reading for this is the way [prototype extends the DOM](http://prototypejs.org/learn/extensions).

And for an idea inside the code (which is too large to reproduce here) you can find [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/dom/dom.js) (Search for `Element.extend`).

In two words, they cannot extend the objects from start, so they extend them with each of their functions that return DOM elements.