# HTML DOM Extension = bad, but is this OK?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I realize that in no way do I want to do:

```
Element.protoype.myfunc = function () {}
```

But, is this the same or not and is this a good practice?

```
var e = document.querySelector(q);
    e.html = function (html) {
        this.innerHTML = html;
    }
e.html("Am I in trouble?");
```

Comment: It's not the same, but I wouldn't call that good practice either...

Comment: I'm not worried about conflictions since all added functions to the object would be under a single class, such as e.myclass.html(""). Other than that, are there any real issues with assigning a function to a DOM object returned in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending `Element` will not work in all browsers (notably IE<8). See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592815/is-there-really-no-way-to-expose-the-prototype-of-a-html-element-in-ie-8)

Extending single elements may result in memory leaks: if such elements are deleted, the method  can still exist, containing a link to the non existent element. See [this link](http://www.josh-davis.org/node/7) (it's about handler methods, but it can also apply to extension methods afaik).

Comment: Forget about Element... What about a document.getElementById(id) object?

Comment: So basically, If the element is removed from the DOM then anything I attached to it with JavaScript will still remain, but attached to nothing?

Comment: If e is defined in the scope of a function, won't e be released after the execution of the function, like the other variables?

Comment: e (presuming you mean `event`) has nothing to do with it. Removing an element from the DOM doesn't nessecary remove the method, that's the idea. In some browsers the garbage collector can't clean up references to these methods. See also: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19564

Comment: I meant e as in my example, var e = document.querySelector(q). This line from the link you posted is extremely relevant: You can't have active references to dead elements or unused data structures. If you do then they won't be cleaned up by the garbage collector. Thanks.