# JavaScript Prototype Appending a Method to DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Some objects in javascript can be appended a method to it.
For example we can have `Array.prototype.pop = function() {...}`

So what I wanna ask is that can we append a method to DOM elements?

Suppose I have the following

```
var x = document.getElementById("hello");
x.toggle();
```

How can I append a method called `toggle` to DOM elements just like what we do in jquery??

Thank you so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, can you extend the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779880/in-javascript-can-you-extend-the-dom)

Comment: Also related: [Is there really no way to expose the prototype of a html element in IE (<8)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592815/is-there-really-no-way-to-expose-the-prototype-of-a-html-element-in-ie-8)

Answer (score 1):

In concept, [you can append functions](http://jsfiddle.net/PFGGj/) since DOM elements are Objects after all. In practice, however, you should avoid doing it. [Circular references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) is one of the issues that is related to binding objects to DOM elements which can cause memory "leakage"