# MOO tools getting type error - "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, mootools

So I'm very unfamiliar with MOO tools and I am getting a type error each time I use a function, like hasClass or removeClass. I have almost no experience with MOO tools and am at a complete loss. I looked in the docs and the syntax is correct.

Here's the code, the error occurs on line 354: "TypeError: li.removeClass is not a function" 
http://pastebin.com/G63003DG

I checked in the moo tools docs and the syntax for removeClass is fine. Running the latest version of moo tools.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions related to code **must include the relevant code in the question itself** (not off-site).

Comment: Can you reproduce that on a jsFiddle adding html also?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this means that you're trying to use the function on an object that *isn't* a MooTools-extended DOM object.

Almost any time you get a DOM object *from MooTools*, it will be extended before you get it. And that's also true for any browser where MooTools can extend the *prototype* of DOM elements. But older versions of IE (IE8 and earlier) don't have HTML element prototypes, so MooTools can't extend the prototypes, and each element has to be extended manually. If you get an element directly from a DOM property (`firstChild`, `nextSibling`, ...), unless it's been extended previously, it won't have MooTools' extensions on it yet. To extend it, pass it through the `$()` function:

```
$(li).removeClass("the-class");
```

Again, this basically only comes up in IE8 (still in wide use) and earlier, because MooTools can extend the *prototype* of HTML elements on other browsers; but older versions of IE don't provide element prototypes and so elements must be extended element-by-element.

Here's an example that fails in IE8: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/iLUXUQI/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/iLUXUQI/1/edit)

```
var li = document.getElementById('theitem');
li.onclick = function() {
    li.addClass('myClass');
};
```

And an example that works in IE8 (the only change is `li` => `$(li)`): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/iLUXUQI/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/iLUXUQI/2/edit)

```
var li = document.getElementById('theitem');
li.onclick = function() {
    $(li).addClass('myClass');
};
```

Comment: @Sergio: Yeah, I didn't think it was you. :-)

Comment: you got it right. dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075790/why-do-i-need-to-do-document-body-to-extend-document-body-with-mootools-eleme - and several other similar ones.

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't my problem -- the error occurs in all browsers and I have tried it with and without $(element).

Comment: @ChrisScott: You'll need to heed the advice from the comments on the question, then. :-) Create a [*minimal* replicating example](http://sscce.org), I'm sure we can point out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix the problem. Turns out a boolean was not evaluating as intended and an event wasn't firing. Your advice helped fix other related errors though.