# A code to stop this ad?

Tags: html, ads

I found this code which I think is an add-on on my website but I can't delete it. Is there a code to stop it automatically instead of clicking on the close button?

```
    <body id="welcome_index" class="default">
<div id="ad_website_top">
         <a href="http://www.e-monsite.com?utm_campaign=network_top_link" class="ad_link_brand">Créer un site gratuitement</a>
      <a href="#" class="ad_link_close">Close</a>
   <div class="ad_banner" style="display:block;">
   <script type="text/javascript">var branddomain = "e-monsite.com";    var siteid = "4fd34212064e2ef6f5adda92";    var lang = "fr";    var whitelist = "default";</script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.e-monsite.com/ads/adtop.js?v=568"></script>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper_container">
```

Comment: Is your hosting free?

Comment: You are using a free website host.  Pay for monthly hosting if you want the add removed.

Comment: @TopherEllis There are free hosting services without ads

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could just remove the element from the DOM using jQuery? See the documentation for [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
$('#welcome_index').remove();
```

Or using vanilla JavaScript:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}

document.getElementById("welcome_index").remove();
```

Comment: What's the `NodeList.prototype.remove` for?

Comment: I'm not sure if IE supports modifying `Element.prototype`. Something about COM objects being unalterable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/592823/1529630

Comment: thanks a lot!  http://aventuriers-passifs.e-monsite.com/en/ but not finished yet...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a free hosting which includes ads. I don't recommend you to remove them, because I'm sure that's against the Terms of service that you accepted after reading carefully.

Instead, I recommend you to

- Pay for a "real" hosting.
- Use a free hosting without ads, e.g. [x10hosting](https://www.x10hosting.com/), [Nixiweb](http://www.nixiweb.com/).